# How To Make Onboarding Screen Only One Time

Tags: flutter, dart, time

> I wanna make my onboarding screen shown only one time when install application in the device
>
> import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
> import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';
>
> import 'widget_tree.dart';
>
> class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget {
> @override
> _IntroScreenState createState() => _IntroScreenState();
> }
>
> class _IntroScreenState extends State {
> final introKey = GlobalKey();
> late final bool isFirstRun;
> get child => null;
>
> void *onIntroEnd(context) {
> Navigator.of(context).push(
> MaterialPageRoute(builder: (*) => WidgetTree()),
> );
> }
>
> Widget _buildFullscreenImage() {
> return Image.asset(
> 'assets/images/intro1.png',
> fit: BoxFit.cover,
> height: double.infinity,
> width: double.infinity,
> alignment: Alignment.center,
> );
> }
>
> Widget _buildImage(String assetName, [double width = 350]) {
> return Image.asset('assets/$assetName', width: width);
> }
>
> @override
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> const bodyStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0);
>
> ```
> const pageDecoration = PageDecoration(
>   titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
>       color: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 116, 182),
>       fontSize: 30.0,
>       fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
>       fontFamily: 'assets/fonts/Ubuntu-B.ttf'),
>   bodyTextStyle: bodyStyle,
>   bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0),
>   pageColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
>   imagePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
> );
>
> return IntroductionScreen(
>   key: introKey,
>   globalBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
>   globalHeader: const Align(
>     alignment: Alignment.topRight,
>     child: SafeArea(
>       child: Padding(
>         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, right: 16),
>         // child: _buildImage('flutter.png', 100),
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
>   /*globalFooter: SizedBox(
>     width: double.infinity,
>     height: 60,
>     child: ElevatedButton(
>       style:const ButtonStyle(alignment:Alignment(1, 1)),
>       child: const Text(
>         'Skip!',
>         style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
>       ),
>       onPressed: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
>     ),
>   ),*/
>
>   pages: [
>     PageViewModel(
>       title: ('WELCOME'),
>       body:
>           'To the Mawed , which allows you to book a clinic easily . Choose the hospital that suits you and the doctor you want.',
>       image: Image.asset(
>         'assets/images/intro1.png',
>         width: 400,
>         height: 400,
>         fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
>         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
>       ),
>       decoration: pageDecoration,
>     ),
>     PageViewModel(
>       title: "Book Now",
>       body: " From your home easly & Keep the ticket to show when asked",
>       image: Image.asset(
>         'assets/images/intro2.jpg',
>         width: 350,
>         height: 350,
>         fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
>         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
>       ),
>       decoration: pageDecoration,
>     ),
>     PageViewModel(
>       title: "Avoid",
>       body: "Crowding and wasting time, and go on time.",
>       image: Image.asset(
>         'assets/images/intro3.jpg',
>         width: 350,
>         height: 350,
>         fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
>         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
>       ),
>       decoration: pageDecoration,
>     ),
>     PageViewModel(
>       title: "Choose the hospital",
>       body: "That suits & the closest to you",
>       image: Image.asset(
>         'assets/images/intro4.jpg',
>         width: 350,
>         height: 350,
>         fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
>         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
>       ),
>       decoration: pageDecoration,
>     ),
>     PageViewModel(
>       title: "What do you feel ?",
>       body: "Choose the clinic or medical specialty carefully",
>       image: Image.asset('assets/images/intro5.png',
>           width: 350,
>           height: 350,
>           fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
>           alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center),
>       decoration: pageDecoration,
>     ),
>     PageViewModel(
>       title: "Get to know ",
>       body: "Your doctor's appointments and choose the time you want.",
>       image: Image.asset('assets/images/intro6.png',
>           width: 400,
>           height: 400,
>           fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
>           alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter),
>       decoration: pageDecoration,
>     ),
>   ],
>   onDone: () => _onIntroEnd(context),
>   onSkip: () => _onIntroEnd(context), // You can override onSkip callback
>   showSkipButton: false,
>   skipOrBackFlex: 0,
>   nextFlex: 0,
>   showBackButton: true,
>   //rtl: true, // Display as right-to-left
>   back: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
>   skip: const Text('Skip', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
>   next: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
>   done:
>       const Text('Book Now', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
>   curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
>   controlsMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
>   controlsPadding: kIsWeb
>       ? const EdgeInsets.all(12.0)
>       : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
>   dotsDecorator: const DotsDecorator(
>     size: Size(10.0, 10.0),
>     color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
>     activeSize: Size(22.0, 10.0),
>     activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
>       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
>     ),
>   ),
>   dotsContainerDecorator: const ShapeDecoration(
>     color: Colors.black87,
>     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
>       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
>     ),
>   ),
> );
> ```
>
> }
> }

Answer (score 10):

The common way to handle this is to use the [SharedPreferences library](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

1- When displaying the onboarding, store a `bool` like `hasSeenOnboarding` in the SharedPreferences with the value `true`
2- Right before displaying the onboarding, fetch the bool `hasSeenOnboarding` from the preferences.
If it's `false`, you can display the onboarding, otherwise you should skip it

Answer (score 5):

As other answers are recommending the use of SharedPreferences or LocalSave, it works fine when you don't have any user account.

If you have user account and a database you should save this status in their profile so even if they install the application on a new device they don't have the onboarding again that could cause issues if you set some specific data that should only be accessed once by the user.

You basically have a `bool hasCompletedOnboarding` set to `false` when creating the user and you update it once he finishes the onboarding.

Then as FDuhen specified you show or not the Onboarding.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use this [Library](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

you will be able to save the data locally by configuring it only once

Answer (score 1):

Using [shared preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), you can show onboarding screen only one time.

```
static SharedPreferences? prefsInstance;
static void init() async {
    prefsInstance = await prefsFuture;
  }
```

set preference while completing onboarding screen Or last page's on click of button which move to dashboard or next screen after done onboarding.

```
prefsInstance!.setBool("IS_FIRST_INSTALLED", true);
```

Now get preference  in splash and check if onboarding already seen or not.

```
 if (SharedPrefUtils.getSharedPreference(IS_FIRST_INSTALLED) == false) {
      /// move to onboarding screen 
      /// onboarding is not seen yet.
    } else {
      /// move to dashboard/home screen - onboarding is already seen
    }
```

```
static Future<dynamic> getSharedPreference(String key) async {
    dynamic value;
    if (prefsInstance == null) {
      var instance = await prefsFuture;
      value = instance!.get(key);
    } else {
      value = get(key);
    }
    return value;
  }
```